# Linking xsl to XML not working when a target namespace is defined

Tags: xml, xslt

I have created an XML file and transformed it into HTML using xsl.  However, when I add a target namespace to the XML file, my browser does not process the file correctly.  When I remove the target namespace, it works fine.

The XML is as follows:

```
<root  xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance'
 xmlns='http://xml.netbeans.org/schema/XmlSchema'
 xsi:schemaLocation='http://xml.netbeans.org/schema/XmlSchema XmlSchema.xsd'>
```

When the line  `xmlns='http://xml.netbeans.org/schema/XmlSchema'` is present in the XML, the browser does not process it correctly. When this line is removed, it works correctly.  What is the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem appears to be that you do not handle the `http://xml.netbeans.org/schema/XmlSchema` namespace in your XSLT file.

I guess... it's a shame that I have to guess - how do you think someone can tell you where the problem is whith your code when you do not show your code?

So, I guess you have something like this:

```
<xsl:stylesheet 
  version="1.0" 
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
>
  <xsl:template match="root">
    <!-- etc ... -->
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

where you *should* have

```
<xsl:stylesheet 
  version="1.0" 
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:xs='http://xml.netbeans.org/schema/XmlSchema'
>
  <xsl:template match="xs:root">
    <!-- etc ... -->
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Not the namespace handling. Adapt your XSLT accordingly.

Comment: If you ask me to put XSL  code, I would! I never know that I have to handle the namespace in XSL file before . It works with me, thank you.

Comment: @Alaa Good to hear. Next time a question that does not require psychic debugging, please. ;)